# Convert HTML Response to PHP Array

Tags: php, html, decode

The response I am getting from a web call in php is something i have never seen. I have tried `json_decode` function and I have also tried the `parse_str` below, but I can't get the values to return in an array.

What i want to do is to output an array with name, price, and url. The formatting of the return has got me stumped (I copied it exactly, no typos or missing ' characters).

```
$urltest='https://www.***';
$result408 = file_get_contents($urltest);
//parse_str($result408, $output);

Prices = [{'name':'Seller1', 'unknown':'unknown0',  'price':60.37, 'price_f':'$60<sup style="font-size:12px;">37</sup>', 'url':'http:…'},
        {'name':'Seller2', 'unknown':'unknown0','price':87.25, 'price_f':'$87<sup style="font-size:12px;">25</sup>, 'url':'http:…'},
        {'name':'Seller3', 'unknown':'unknown0',  'price':74, 'price_f':'$74<sup style="font-size:12px;">00</sup>', 'url':'http:…'}];
```

Comment: there is no coma between ``` 'price_f':'$7400'‘url’:’http:…’ ```

Comment: Ask your data provider to fix the invalid json format

Comment: That looks like invalid JSON, strings should be wrapped in double quotes not single, as well as missing commas etc.

Comment: It is clearly not a valid jSon format as it have a lot of errors like missing comma, wrong and missing quotes so you can ask to who provide to you this response to encode it as valid jSon or if yourself have access to fix it.

Comment: ok i have fixed the typos-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON returned from the service is bad. It looks like you can 
alter it to make it into JSON that can be parsed. 
Bear in mind this approach **assumes that there are no single quotes
in any of the data values**.

$tmp=str_replace('gSellPrices =', '',$result408); 
$tmp = str_replace('"', '\"', $tmp); 
$tmp = str_replace('\'', '"', $tmp); 
$tmp = rtrim($tmp, '; ');

```
$urltest='https://www.***';
$result408 = file_get_contents($urltest);
// Remove 'Prices = '
$tmp=str_replace('gSellPrices =', '',$result408);
// Protect the existing double quotes
$tmp = str_replace('"', '\\"', $tmp);
// Now replace all the incorrect single quotes with double quotes.
$tmp = str_replace('\'', '"', $tmp);
// Remove trailing semicolon
$tmp = rtrim($tmp, '; ');
// Now we can json_decode
$data = json_decode($tmp);


Assuming that the output from service is EXACTLY as follows:

Prices = [{'name':'Seller1', 'unknown':'unknown0',  'price':60.37, 'price_f':'$60<sup style="font-size:12px;">37</sup>', 'url':'http:…'},
    {'name':'Seller2', 'unknown':'unknown0','price':87.25, 'price_f':'$87<sup style="font-size:12px;">25</sup>, 'url':'http:…'},
    {'name':'Seller3', 'unknown':'unknown0',  'price':74, 'price_f':'$74<sup style="font-size:12px;">00</sup>', 'url':'http:…'}];
```

Comment: getting very close but now all of the ' were replaced with \"    etc  \"name\":\"unknown1\"

Comment: It is not doing backslashes for me. Where are you seeing that?

Comment: tmp":"[{\"name\":\"Seller1\",\"unknown\":\"unknown0\",\"price\":60.37,\"price_f\":\"$60<supstyle=\"font-size:12px;\">37<\/sup>\",\"url\":\"http:..\"},"data":null  if you would like to private chat i can

Comment: We can move this discussion to chat.

Comment: I cant find chat button

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for json_decode ( http://php.net/manual/tr/function.json-decode.php )

```
urltest='https://www.***';
$result408 = file_get_contents($urltest);
$output = json_decode($result408);
```

Comment: as metioned above i tried jason_decode and because of the errors in the return infromation it does not work returns null...